How to sync Salesforce customers to Netsuite using suitescript?
I have created user event script to sync customer from Netsuite to Salesforce. If customer is created/edited in Netsuite, it will be created/edited in Salesforce. Now, I want to do vice versa.  I want to sync Salesforce customers to Netsuite. If customer is created/edited in Salesforce, it should be created/edited in Netsuite using suitescript. How it would be possible? Please advice.
Below is user event script to sync Netsuite customers to Salesforce:
function afterSubmit(context) {
    // Get access token for Salesforce
    var accessToken = 'jhbfjsegbrfhbehgb';

    if (context.type === context.UserEventType.CREATE) {
        var rec = context.newRecord;
        var customerId = rec.id;
        var name = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'companyname' });

        try {
            // Create customer in Salesforce
            var createBody = {
                Name: name
            };
            var createSalesforceResponse = createSalesforceCustomer(accessToken, createBody);
            log.debug("createSalesforceResponse", createSalesforceResponse);

            if (createSalesforceResponse.success) {
                record.submitFields({
                    type: rec.type,
                    id: customerId,
                    values: {
                        custentity_sf_customer_id: createSalesforceResponse.id
                    }
                });
                log.debug("Customer Created in Salesforce", "Customer ID: " + createSalesforceResponse.id);
            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to create customer in Salesforce: ' + JSON.stringify(createSalesforceResponse.error));
            }

        } catch (e) {
            log.error('Error creating customer in Salesforce', e.message);
        }
    } else if (context.type === context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
        var rec = context.newRecord;
        var salesforceCustomerId = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'custentity_sf_customer_id' });
        log.debug("salesforceCustomerId", salesforceCustomerId);
        var name = rec.getValue({ fieldId: 'companyname' });

        try {
            // Update customer in Salesforce
            var updateBody = {
                City__c: "Kochi"
            };
            log.debug("calling salesforceResponse", "calling salesforceResponse");
            var updateSalesforceResponse = updateSalesforceCustomer(accessToken, updateBody, salesforceCustomerId);

        } catch (e) {
            log.error('Error creating customer in Salesforce', e.message);
        }
    }
}

function createSalesforceCustomer(accessToken, customerData) {
    var response = https.post({
        url: 'https://abc4-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Customer/',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(customerData)
    });

    var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
    if (response.code === 201) {
        return {
            success: true,
            id: responseBody.id
        };
    } else {
        log.error('Error creating customer in Salesforce', responseBody);
        return {
            success: false,
            error: responseBody
        };
    }
}

function updateSalesforceCustomer(accessToken, updateData, salesforceId) {
    log.debug('salesforceId parameter', salesforceId);

    var response = https.post({
        url: 'https://abc4-dev-ed.develop.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v61.0/sobjects/Customer/' + salesforceId + '?_HttpMethod=PATCH',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updateData)
    });

    log.debug('response', response);
}


Use scheduled script or map/reduce script to get data from Sales Force into NetSuite.

If I have to pass salesforce data to NetSuite RESTlet as a parameter how this can be achieved?

if its get request pass the data as querystring parameters and if its post request then you pass the json as post request payload.
